# connect to SQL using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, database-connection

anyone can help me to connect to SQL server through vb.net using asp.net webform.. I have the database name Users and i want to use the database for the login page.. please help me..

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim ConnectionString As String 
    ConnectionString = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("ConnectionString")
    Dim con As New SqlConnection(ConnectionString) 
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("Select UserId, Pwd from Users", con) 
    con.Open()
    Dim myreader As SqlDataReader
    myreader = cmd.ExecuteReader() 
    While myreader.Read()
        If TxtUserId.Text = myreader("UserId").ToString().Trim() 
           AndAlso TxtPwd.Text = myreader("Pwd").ToString().Trim() Then
            Session("UserId") = TxtUserId.Text 
            Response.Redirect("UserMyProfile.aspx") 
        Else 
            lblMsg.Visible = True 
            lblMsg.Text = "Inavalid UserId/Password" 
        End If
    End While
    con.Close() 
End Sub
```

Comment: Google can help you... lots of examples http://www.startvbdotnet.com/ado/sqlserver.aspx

Comment: i have tried the code already.. but, when i debug, there are some errors.. i'm a beginner in asp.net..

Comment: @tan keng: If you're getting specific errors, you can ask a question here about those errors.  We're happy to help.

Comment: It's better to post what you have tried and what errors you are encountering, from that point you will get the help you need.

Comment: i tried that coding before.. but there are still some errors

Comment: Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As
System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
Dim ConnectionString As String
ConnectionString=ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("ConnectionString")
Dim con As New SqlConnection(ConnectionString)
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("Select UserId, Pwd from Users", con)
con.Open()
Dim myreader As SqlDataReader
myreader=cmd.ExecuteReader()
While myreader.Read()
If TxtUserId.Text=myreader("UserId").ToString().Trim()
AndAlso TxtPwd.Text=myreader("Pwd").ToString().Trim() Then
Session("UserId")=TxtUserId.Text
Response.Redirect("UserMyProfile.aspx")

Comment: @tan keng: Please add the code to the question, not as a comment.  It's easier to read when properly formatted in the question.  Also, include any error messages you see.  "Some errors" doesn't really narrow it down.  It's likely that the system is telling you what's wrong with the error message.

Comment: there are some errors which said that SqlConnection, SqlCommand, and SqlDataRead are not defined

Comment: @tan keng: Are you importing the correct namespace?  See the edit to my answer below.

Comment: where should i add? sorry, i'm newbie here..

Answer (score 1):

There's no shortage of tutorials on the web for this, but a good starting point is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178371.aspx).

**EDIT:** Based on your comments above, it sounds like you're not importing the `Namespace` you need for the ADO.NET data objects.  Try adding this to the class file:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
```

Comment: david, do u have some sample of asp.net web? i want to study more about asp.net since i'm newbie for asp.net

Comment: @tan keng: There's really no shortage of examples and tutorials online.  Google can give you a lot more than I can.  (Additionally, I'm not a very good teacher.  My example applications won't be... beginner level.)  Also, "I want to learn ASP.NET" is way too broad a topic for Stack Overflow.  Specific questions, such as the code you posted and the errors you saw, are great here.  But this isn't really a tutorial site.